# Where can we store 3rd party application passwords?

Tags: 8, security

I've written a Drupal 8 custom module that communicates with 3rd party APIs which need authentication. I have an application username and password for those APIs which I need to store somewhere. I can think of the following two ways to achieve that.

1. I can store the credentials in the Drupal database as configuration. But the password then becomes visible in plain text to all the site admins, and we don't want all the site admins to see the password (I also am aware that we can set up roles and permissions, so we can disable access to a particular configuration for all the site admins, but still the password is saved in plain text in the database).
2. I can also store the credentials in the settings.php file.

Is there any other way we can store these credentials? What is the best, secure and preferred way to store 3rd party account credentials in Drupal 8?

Comment: Instead of your form submit saving to site config, you could perform a DB merge query. This would always leave your form empty...

Comment: @Prestosaurus Can you please explain what you meant by doing a DB merge query? Where will the password get saved to? If I put the field type as password, it wouldn't be visible in the form. But it'll always be visible when we go to Configuration Synchronization and view the configuration there.

Comment: `but still the password is saved in plain text in the database` well... you gotta trust your admins. Even if you encrypt the text, they could prob still decrypt it if they have access to your file system.

Comment: Some of these 3rd parties have settings where you can set it so that it only works from your specific domain name.

Comment: If the DB isn’t enough to suit your requirements, something out of the public root I guess is the option like settings.php. But then you’re outside of the Drupal management system too.  But I agree above, if direct DB data Access and/or permissions don’t cut it, options are short

Comment: More to the point, if your database doesn’t offer the level of security you require, I don’t think code would be my recommendation for a resolution. Structuring of roles and access delegation would be the key

Comment: Sorry, don't want this to be an 'end of the road'. With a DB insert/merge you could create a custom DB table which could be truncated from any distribution for those that administer your site. But you would still face the issue that Production would include all this info, but it might be a way to further limit access to sensitive data.

Comment: Doesn't the API provide an access token? You really shouldn't store a full access username and password anywhere.

Comment: Doesn't that 3rd party application provide oauth in the first place? Simply let that replace your Drupal login. Never ever store user's 3rd party passwords in your Drupal!!!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you're looking for a Drupal-centric solution, the [Key module](https://www.drupal.org/project/key) might provide what you're looking for. It supports pulling your stored secrets from a few different locations:

- Config
- File
- Environment Variable
- 3rd party services

As far a *best*, there's really no one-size-fits-all answer. It depends on your data storage requirements and what you're protecting (e.g. an API key for a medical records REST API should have heavy restrictions whereas a Slack webhook is pretty low risk).

If you're wanting a scalable solution, you might want to consider one of the many 3rd party services that provide secret management.

Comment: Thanks for letting know of this module. This has so many features apart from easy ways to fetch the content stored in several places like Drupal Config, File system, etc.
If I store the password in settings.php, I can access it from the Custom Module code that I've written. Can a Drupal Admin see the contents of the settings.php file?

Comment: If you've configured the site such that an admin can't inject arbitrary PHP (e.g. Devel module, PHP field, etc.) you should be fine.

Answer (score -2):

What about creating a specific permission *'view users password'* and give it only to specified user's role *'super admin'*? And disable this permission for basic *'administrator'* role?

Then your users may store 3rd party app passwords in specified fields and your admins won't see it.